# JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY storing objects

Tags: jquery, variables, this, storage

Story: I need to store JQuery('') into an array for further work.

My semi-functinal solution (not working properly):

```
    var myArray = new Array();
    var $selected_place;

    function addPlace(){
        var new_place = jQuery('<div/>', {
            class: 'place'
        });

        new_place.click(function(){
             doSomething($(this));
        });

        myArray[myArray.length] = new_place;
    }
```

The problem:

```
function doSomething(link) {
    var number;
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if (myArray[i] == link){
            number= i;
            break;
        } //end of if
    } //end of for
    alert(number);
} //end of function
```

The alert always returns only 'undefined'.

THE SOLUTION:

Replacing the $(this) for a global variable solved my problem, now its working properly.
     $selected_place = new_place;
and in the doSomething method/function the if statement
     myArray[i] == $selected_place

Comment: try storing the values in a specific object like this, var obj = {

    aFunction: function(){
    alert("test");
    }

    }

    //then in your dom ready state

    obj.aFunction(); //invokes the function

Comment: you can call stored variables like this obj.storedvar

Comment: so u suggest to store the value as a function returning that value? am i correct? Instead of using var selected_place = new_place... use var selected_place = {getValue: function(){return new_place}}; ?

Comment: Hello Ales, you can use a function to return the value - really only if it needs more functionality going on, maths etc... otherwise you can just store it like this - obj.storedvalue = 2; then to call it again during a function - just call the space obj.storedvalue

Comment: var selected_place = {getValue: function(){ var newerVal = this.storedval + newVal; return newerVal }};

Answer (score 0):

selected_place and/or myArray is empty.
Pass it as a argument to function doSomething()

Comment: `selected_place` and `myArray` are defined globally, so they should be accessible to the function.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because myArray does not contain the value of $selected_place. You are probably invoking your functions in the wrong order.

Just a nitpick though:

You can use `myArray.push(new_place)` to accomplish `myArray[myArray.length] = new_place;`

Comment: how could it NOT contain the value if i assign the value here : $selected_place = new_place; and the value/object 'new_place' is also assign to the array... ? THX for answer

Comment: The way that could happen is if `addPlace()` is called *after* `doSomething()`. Another problem that could occur is that your code might be wrapped in a document ready handler, in which case `selected_place` and `myArray` are not globals..

Comment: i tried to move all of the globals out of the ready function but it really didnt make any difference.. but what i found was that when i was sending the div as a $(this) it has a different poniter value (problably ?) than the one stored in array

Comment: @AlešMenzel Please post your full js file.

Comment: its because THIS is probably out of scope  - before going into a function make a var called THAT. --- so var that = this; function(){that.mystoredvar}